# Create random objects from a Product class

Tags: java, random

I have a Product class that represent a Product:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Product {
    private int productId;
    private String productType;
    private String brand;
    private double price;

    public Product(int productId, String productType, String brand, double price)
    {
        this.productId = productId;
        this.productType = productType;
        this.brand = brand;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int getProductId() {
        return this.productId;
    }

    public void setProductId(int productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }

    public String getProductType() {
        return this.productType;
    }

    public void setProductType(String productType) {
        this.productType = productType;
    }

    public String getBrand() {
        return this.brand;
    }

    public void setBrand(String brand) {
        this.brand = brand;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return this.price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

Now, in my program, I want to create 3 random objects of this Product class, and here is my code for that:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Product> products = new ArrayList();
    Random r = new Random();

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        products.add(new Product(1337, "Type", "Brand", 300.33));
    }
}
```

Now, my question is how do I implement so that the random class creates random values? I have created static values for the products, so how do I randomize it so I get 3 different values?

Comment: When the 'relevant' code uses no Swing classes, it's a good hint that the [tag:swing] tag is not relevant to the problem. So don't add it!

Comment: How do you expect a randomized string (for type and brand) to be? Or a randomized id?

Comment: I'm downvoting because on the very top of google search result("java generate random string") I find multiple articles showing you how to do this.

Comment: Do you have a fix set of valid values for brand, id, ... or what does "randomized" mean for you? Is "MyArbitraryWeirdBrand" random enough? Or even "khkghfjkbvnmdk"?

Comment: Is the static value with a number appended random enough?

Comment: Explain what properties of Product you expect to randomize. Otherwise you won't be answered

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing which element of `Product` you want to randomize, one can only keep guessing. The code given below is not the solution to your question; rather, it is to give you a pointer about how you can use the randomly generated values:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class Product {
    private int productId;
    private String productType;
    private String brand;
    private double price;

    public Product(int productId, String productType, String brand, double price) {
        this.productId = productId;
        this.productType = productType;
        this.brand = brand;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int getProductId() {
        return this.productId;
    }

    public void setProductId(int productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }

    public String getProductType() {
        return this.productType;
    }

    public void setProductType(String productType) {
        this.productType = productType;
    }

    public String getBrand() {
        return this.brand;
    }

    public void setBrand(String brand) {
        this.brand = brand;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return this.price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Product [productId=" + productId + ", productType=" + productType + ", brand=" + brand + ", price="
                + price + "]";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
        Random r = new Random(10);
        int num;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            num = r.nextInt(10);
            products.add(new Product(r.nextInt(10000), "Type" + num, "Brand" + num, 1000 * r.nextDouble()));
        }
        products.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Product [productId=2380, productType=Type3, brand=Brand3, price=257.8027905957804]
Product [productId=1456, productType=Type6, brand=Brand6, price=244.11725056425314]
Product [productId=6214, productType=Type1, brand=Brand1, price=370.6111260136414]
```

Feel free to comment should you need any further help.